# Ivy: <ivy:settings> vs. <ivy:configure>

Tags: ivy

I have a master Ivy project that others include in their project via a `svn:externals` property. The project contains the Ivy jar, the default ivysettings.xml file that connects to our project, and a few Ant macros that allows me to standardize the way we build jars, etc. (For example, users use `<jar.macro>` vs. `<jar>`. The `<jar.macro>` uses the same parameters, but also automatically embeds the `pom.xml` in the jar and adds in Jenkins build information into the Manifest).

We also use Jenkins as our continuous integration system. One of the things I want to do is to clean the Ivy cache for each build, so we don't have any jar issues due to cache problems. To do this, I've setup my `ivysettings.xml` file to define a separate cache for each Jenkins Executor:

```
<ivysettings>
    <property name="env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER" value="0" override="false"/>
    <caches
        defaultCacheDir="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/cache-${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}"
        resolutionCacheDir="${ivy.dir}/../target/ivy.cache"/>
    <settings defaultResolver="default"/>
    <include file="${ivy.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/>
</ivysettings>
```

I originally used the `<ivy:settings>` task to configure our projects with Ivy. However, all of the Jenkins executors were using the same Ivy cache which caused problems. I switched from `<ivy:settings>` to `<ivy:configure>` and the problem went away. Apparently, `<ivy:configure>` sets up Ivy immediately (and thus sets up the caches correctly) while `<ivy:settings>` doesn't set Ivy up until `<ivy:resolve>` is called.

I've seen some emails on Nabble about `<ivy:configure>` being deprecated (or maybe not). I see nothing in the Ivy online documentation stating `<ivy:configure>` is being deprecated.

So, when would you use `<ivy:settings>` vs. `<ivy:configure>`. In my case, since I needed separate caches for each Jenkins executor, I needed to use `<ivy:configure>`, but is there a reason I might use `<ivy:settings>` over `<ivy:configure>`? And, is `<ivy:configure>` deprecated?

Comment: Excellent question. I have never used the "configure" task. I suspect the settings task is more useful because it would enable you to perform several ivy resolve tasks, using more than one ivy settings file. Since I rarely invoke an ivy resolve more than once, it would appear there is no real functional difference between the tasks in my case :-)

Comment: Except that both `<ivy:configure>` and `<ivy:settings>` can take a _settings ID_, so they both seem to be able to use multiple settings and multiple resolves. It explicitly mentions this in the `<ivy:settings>` docs, but it appears that both tasks support this features. I believe `<ivy:settings>` is the default one to use in Ivy 2.x, but in my case, my `<ivy:cleancache>` caused problems with `<ivy:settings>` but not with `<ivy:configure>`.

Comment: Perhaps this question is best posted onto the developer mailing list. Like I said I rarely perform an ivy resolve more than once in a build. That explains why I never need to specify the settings ID. Yeah it's a bit of a puzzle

Comment: I've posted this on the user mailing list. I'll have to see if I get any response. If not, I'll post it to the developer list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's what I found:

- `<ivy:settings>` is newer and the *preferred* way.
- `<ivy:configure>` may or may not be deprecated.
- `<ivy:settings>` doesn't set my Ivy settings until `<ivy:resolve>` is called while `<ivy:configure>` sets all Ivy settings as soon as the task is executed.

The last one is my issue. Since I have parallel Jenkins builds going on, and I want to start out each build with a completely clean cache, I use customized cache settings depending upon the Jenkins executor number. The caches are labeled `cache-0` through `cache-5`.

However, since `<ivy:settings>` isn't executed until I call `<ivy:resolve>`, my customized cache settings aren't picked up. I call `<ivy:cleancache>` before I call Ivy resolve which causes the builds to clean out a common cache. Hilarity ensues. Using `<ivy:cofnfigure>` fixes this problem.